# Identifying target machine (32 bit or 64 bit) with ClickOnce deployment

Tags: .net, winforms, deployment, clickonce, 32bit-64bit

I have a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application and am deploying that application through ClickOnce deployment. Now, I've a third-party DLL file and it has different versions for 32-bit and 64-bit OS.

Is it possible to deploy different DLL files based on the target machine (32-bit or 64-bit) through ClickOnce?

Comment: Do the two different dll versions have the same file name?

Comment: @whatknott: Yes, both dlls are having same name, even the version number. Only difference is size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Edit]**

It's not necessary to use reflection. You can add a reference to your program directly in the loader and kick it off. Did a blog post with code about it at [Tech and Me](http://techmikael.blogspot.com/2010/12/identifying-target-machine-32bit-or.html).

---

You could include both versions in your deployment, but name them differently. Then have a loader app check if you are on a 32bit or 64bit system, copy the correct dll (eg thirdparty64.dll -> thirdparty.dll) which your real program is linked to, and then invoke your program from the loader with for example `Assembly.Load` and use reflection to start your main method.

An easier method is to compile your application to run as x86, ensuring it will always run in 32bit mode. If you don´t rely on some specific application being installed on the machine in 32/64bit versions this could be the best choice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is this possible with Clickonce? Is this loader application going to run while clickonce deploys the application or it should be run on my application first run? During the clickonce deployment I'm not sure how do we copy this dll, as I'm not sure whether it gives us the installation location. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You would have to do it once the application runs the first time, not on deployment. I´ll try it myself as well.

Comment: Did a small test project and blog post on this. Edited my answer to reflect it.